# Shell scripting

Tags: java, shell

I have a robocode.jar to extend,and then i want to run it from shell.
I can't run it from shell because i get the following error

```
error: Main method not found in class tema1, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

I've searched ,but no answer helped me.
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
javac -cp robocode.jar: tema1.java
java -cp robocode.jar: tema1
```

My class it's extendig their class and I have to make it work in the game.
http://robocode.sourceforge.net/
When I run it from Eclipse it's working fine,the game starts,but from shell it's not working
Can someone help me figure out what i have to do to make it work from shell and not only from ide?

Comment: `Main method not found in class tema1` You didn't post the class...

Comment: don't have how to put the main class,because it's extending another one named Robot and I'm building my robot from their robot.I have just to make my robot do stuff ,and then play the game.It's working from eclipse,starting the game ,but it won' t start from shell

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you'll have to define a `static` method `main` in your class `tema1` as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* your main program */
}
```

The `main` method is where your program execution starts.

Comment: I don't have how to put the main class,because it's extending another one named Robot and I'm building my robot from their robot.I have just to make my robot do stuff ,and then play the game.It's working from eclipse,starting the game ,but it won' t start from shell

Comment: Then I guess that the starting class isn't `tema1`. Examine the Eclipse configuration to figure out the starting class and call that on the command line.